# How to get stacktraces using the logstashCollector feature of websphere liberty?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm using the logstashCollector-1.0 feature on Liberty 16.0.0.3 to collect logs on a ELK stack.
I followed instructions here for the setup:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_analytics_collectors.html

All is working well, but I do not have any of the stacktraces I'm logging in the code. 
I get the exception message in logstash, but not the stack.
The stack appears in message.log file on the server itself, but are not forwarded by the logstashCollector feature (neither in liberty_trace nor in liberty_message items).

Is there some configuration I can tweak to get the stacktraces, or is it impossible? Not having the stacks is a big showstopper for my devs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack trace was not included to the liberty_message events prior to Liberty 17.0.0.1.  There was no server configuration users can set to add this.

In Liberty 17.0.0.1, the stack trace has been appended to the message field of the liberty_message events.  No configuration change is required.

See Liberty [APAR PI76200](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI76200) for more details.

HTH